# Can I have a button to set the frame of an animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have a button that will set the frame of an animation?
For example, suppose I have this animation:

```css
@keyframes slide {
      0% { left:    0%; }
     20% { left:    0%; }
     25% { left: -100%; }
     45% { left: -100%; }
     50% { left: -200%; }
     70% { left: -200%; }
     75% { left: -300%; }
     95% { left: -300%; }
    100% { left: -400%; }
}
```

How can I set the animation at 20%, or 45%, using a button?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, give this plugin a try: https://github.com/jQueryKeyframes/jQuery.Keyframes